# using tags in rspec for breaking down agile development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, agile

Our specs are taking about 15 minutes to run and am looking for some advice (and really a sanity check for whether our sol'n makes sense). I'd like to create a system where isolated tests can be run separate from the whole suite and also match up to a task from our task list. I've proposed that we tag each of our specs like this:

```
  describe 'task048: call to test mobile api', task048: true do
    render_views
    it 'will test ...'
```

so that we could run:

```
rspec --tag task048
```

to just check a single spec and then run it against our CI server at a later point. It seems to be working well and thinking of doing this for our small team. Does this seem like a reasonable solution? I have limited experience in rspec so just want to be sure I'm not missing a better way.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really an "opinion" question, so I'm not sure it's going to survive, but i think this is a reasonable approach and I'm not aware of any other alternatives. If the `-e` command line option took a regex as an argument, you could perhaps rely on that, but it takes a string and I believe requires a complete match.

Comment: thx Peter for confirmation. We'll just keep doing it this way then

Comment: @timpone I'm glad the answer was helpful, but I'm curious as to why you commented and perhaps upvoted this answer, while you've left no comments, upvotes or accepts on my answers to your two previous questions, both which I considered more substantive. I see you're an experienced SO user, with 460 question and pretty high ratio of accepting answers. Is "commenting/accepting/upvoting" something you just do periodically? You're free to do whatever you want, of course, including not respond to this question ;-) but as I said, I was curious.

Comment: just been busy with work; sorry not more responsive. I do ask a lot of  questions and I appreciate all the answers. I do tend to leave questions open a few days to see if there are other answers. Honestly, would like to hear other sol'ns to this problem but probably not. Again thx for answering all 3.

Comment: @timpone Thanks for this response and the upvotes/accepts. Keeping questions open makes perfect sense and I should have assumed that. FWIW, if I'd seen an upvote, I would have given you the benefit of the doubt that it would have come from you and not have inquired. In any event, feel free to "unaccept" any of these in the hopes of getting additional responses.

Comment: @timpone Also, I ran into an rspec script the other day that I think was using a regex with the `-e` option. It's now definitely on my list of things to check that out.

Comment: thx - really appreciate your answers on this and other questions.